# Infrared connection with programming interface

Tags: windows, infrared

I am looking for a way to establish infrared connection from Windows PC, with programming interface available for C/C++. I tried the following directions:

1. Laptop with InfraRed port: no programming interface. Maybe there are some drivers (like converting to virtual COM port), or any other software solution?
2. Serial to IRDA adaptors - look exactly like I need. Such adaptor can be plugged to PC COM port and available through serial port API. But all products I found are very old and not available anymore.
3. USB to IRDA adaptors - available, but I didn't find anything with programming interface. It would be nice to have such adapter with SDK (like Read, Write functions) or with virtual COM port driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IrCOMM2k](http://www.ircomm2k.de/English/index.html) might work for 1.

Regarding 3, I would have thought that there should be plenty of alternatives available, though they might not be easy to find. For example, [IguanaWorks](http://iguanaworks.net/product1.psp) are selling a USB device that can transmit IR and the driver is open source, so you should be able to look in there for how to send your own commands to it (or contact their support for more info).
And [IRTrans](http://www.irtrans.de/en/technicalinfo/app.php) even has an IR transmitter that can be connected via USB or Wifi and specifically mentions how you can control their device programmatically.

Might be worth looking at [Lirc](http://www.lirc.org/) since they have useful info regarding available devices and might have code you can look at.

A good place to start for anything to do with USB is Jan Axelson's [site](http://www.lvr.com/serport.htm#usb_virtual_com_ports).

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Probably it can take a few days...